# Can't install Azure WebApp Application Insights without Visual Studio

Tags: azure

I have wordpress installed and running in an Microsoft Azure WebApp. When I created the WebApp, the system automatically created Application Insights, which I tried to enable, but unlike on my other WebApps, the server side tracking wasn't working and I couldn't fix it, so I tried to delete it and added a new Application Insights resource...

Unfortunately I can't figure out, how to get it running, sice now I dont have a "deploy" button, to make it work, nor do I have Visual Studio - which every guide recommends to use and is a bit annoying.

What I need to do is install somehow the system monitor for App Insights in my App but can't find out how. (without VS)

Any help appreciated. Thanks

EDIT (SOLVED) :: Justins comment is the solution to this problem.

Comment: Have you looked in to the application insights plugin for WordPress? It may set up all of the necessary things to get the server side tracking. https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-WordPress

Comment: Awesome advice and also the easy solution I was hoping for. Thanks Justin!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the application insights plugin for WordPress. It will set up all of the necessary things to get the server side tracking.

http://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-WordPress